# Is it possible to change the language of chips using ngx-chips library?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-chips

I am using ngx-chips library and this is the representation of the issue i am having:[image]

I have a select language dropdown and I want the languages of the chips to be changed based on the selected language. From the library docs this doesnt seem to be possible.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own template and do the translation.

```
<tag-input theme='bootstrap'  id="test" [(ngModel)]="tagsSelected" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true"
           [clearOnBlur]="true" [maxItems]= "5"  (onAdd)="onModelAdded($event)" (onRemove)="onModelRemoved($event)">

    <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
       ({{ i18Wrap(item.display) }})
    </ng-template>
</tag-input>
```